# уникальные ip адреса

Tags: awk

у меня есть файл в котором такие данные:

```
128.124.53.81 - - [17/May/2021:19:41:50 +0300] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2018/11/baner_PNU_1550x400-e1569401806743.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 151360 "https://x.x.x/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/87.0.4280.163 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"<br>
```

Вывести в файл список уникальных IP-адресов с которых поступали запросы
Я сделал чтобы выводило все ip адреса:`awk '{print $1}' file.txt`, но как сделать уникальные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться связкой команд `sort` + `uniq`.

```
awk '{print $1}' file.txt | sort | uniq
```

`uniq` - читает построчно данные и пропускает строку, если она совпадает с предыдущей. Это значит, что если на вход подать остортированые данные, то на выходе получим только уникальные строки. Именно для этого входные данные нужно отсортировать командой `sort`.